# Dependabot say Kramdown needs security update - but I dont have a gemfile in which the vunerability is supposed to be

Tags: github-pages, kramdown, gemfile.lock, dependabot

I got a dependabot alert (CVE-2020-14001 Vulnerable versions: < 2.3.0 Patched version: 2.3.0) from github for one of my github pages (https://github.com/akademie-oeffentliches-gesundheitswesen/krisenmanagment). This alert is supposed to be in the gemfile.lock. But I dont have that file or a gemfile in this repository, because I switched to a remote theme.

I had several other repositories where I could fix this error message but in this case I am puzzled on where to start.

Comment: Sounds worth a dependabot-core issue. Very hard to see what is happening from outsider view.